# factorial program using foldr and foldl gives stackoverflow and not with product function

Tags: haskell, hugs

I created Factorial program using foldl and foldr as shown below. But when i try to find factorial of large number like 100000 it gives: **ERROR - C stack overflow**

Where as, if i use **product** function it gives me the result after long time.

```
foldl (*) 1 [1..100000] 
product [1..100000]
```

Why am i getting different behavior? I am new to Haskell hence trying to understand different concepts by writing program like these.

Comment: Which `ghc` are you using ? In 7.10.2, it doesn't give me stackoverflow. Also never used `foldl`, always use the strict version `foldl'`

Comment: @Sibi, "ERROR - C stack overflow" is an error message from hugs. That said I don't know why this question has the ghc tag, heh.

Comment: Yes sorry I am using Hugs. This error is from that.

Comment: Yes now i also observed that foldl and foldr are not giving error on using ghci from command prompt but the same is given in WinHugs. Is it very specific to WinHugs?

Comment: if you don't happen to be a student of FP101x (and probably even then) then my best advice would be to drop Hugs and use GHC instead (sorry)

Comment: Sure I will take your advice @Carsten. But could help which is the best book or tutorial to go through for Haskell and functional programming beginner? I am looking forward to take it as full time language and also I am currently into C# and XAML application development.

Comment: I really liked [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) to begin with - although it sadly has no exercises - and if you are working with C# you might be interested in F# too (as you can make use of your .net knowledge while you can get used to functional thinking using a similar syntax to Haskell - although F# is not quite as powerful)

Comment: @BalrajSingh be sure to check out the [info page for the `haskell` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info)